# Find out if resource is used

Tags: android, resources, tracking, drawable

I am looking for an efficient way to find out if a resource (mostly a drawable) is used in Java or in an XML file.

The problem is, that on my current project the drawables are changed often and now I have some drawables, which might never be used.

Is there a tool/way to find those unused drawables without search each filename in the whole project?

Comment: It would be nice to have that kind of script :)

Comment: Well looks like I have to write one :)

Comment: @MaxUsanin thanks for spamming my question. What does your question have to do with my question? This is spam and I have flagged it.

Comment: sorry I found your answer .... I understand that you can help me ... and did not know how to ask you ..

Comment: sorry came here, but I am the @user177168. I've chnged my default username. And I don't know why you continue seeing my name as the defalult.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I wrote a tool based on python to solve this problem. As this is not the place to share it directly, I created a project page which is now offline.

**UPDATE:**
The development has stopped since Lint can do the same and is already included in the Android SDK.

Comment: Hm is it me or is the tool not working? I supplied it with a path to the root folder of my android project. But now it says that there is no file /path/to/project/root/gen/R.java. And that is correct because the R.java file is in gen/de/somepackage/anotherpackage/clientpackage/ Is there a fix for this?

Comment: I guess its better to create a ticket at the project page. I am active, so I will respond quick :)

Comment: Doesn't work, had to hardcode my directory at "parseR(rclass)" it was looking for the R.java in C:\Workspace\Project_dir\gen\CVS\ and I gave the dir option '-i C:\Workspace\Project_dir'.  So it needs more work but I got it to work at least.

Comment: @JPM I don't get it. wasn't C:\Workspace\Project_dir not your project directory? Because in that case the gen folder should be directly in that project folder. Could you be a bit more specific in the error description, please.

Comment: I thought I was, when I ran the program it said it couldn't find the R.java in "C:\Workspace\Project_dir\gen\CVS\".

Comment: Just submitted an issue to the Google Code project. Let me know if you got it.

Comment: @WarrenFaith The Link is broken..Will you please update this?

Comment: @Dharmendra the project has stopped since more than a year. Lint supports all stuff I have done there, so just run lint and you will get what you are looking for...

Comment: @WarrenFaith Hmm. Thanks for your info. Yeah Lint is doing this stuff.

Comment: As a note, Lint is executed in Android Studio via `Analyze -> Inspect Code`.

Answer (score 18):

I just wrote this bash script just for fun:

```
PROJECT="/path/to/the/project"
for file in $(ls $PROJECT/res/drawable -l | awk '{ print $8}' | sed 's/\..\+//g'); do count=0; for SRCFILE in `find $PROJECT -name "*.xml" -print 2> /dev/null`; do let "count+=$(grep -c @drawable/$file $SRCFILE)"; done; for SRCFILE in `find $PROJECT -name "*.java" -print 2> /dev/null`; do let "count+=$(grep -c R.drawable.$file $SRCFILE)"; done; if [ $count -lt 1 ]; then echo -e "\e[0;31m$file\e[0m not used"; else echo -e "\e[0;32m$file\e[0m used"; fi; done;
```

It works fine, though I'm a bash newbie so it can be highly improved:

[image]

It searches drawables resources only (`@drawable/name` on the XML files, and `R.drawable.name` on the Java files).

By the way, I didn't know that `boxscore` and `calendarlogos` were not being used in my project. Another funny fact is that most users don't use Linux, so this won't help too many people.

---

For MacOs would be something like this:

```
PROJECT="/path/to/the/project"
for file in $(ls -l $PROJECT/res/drawable | awk '{ print $9}' | sed 's/\..\+//g'); do count=0; for SRCFILE in `find $PROJECT -name "*.xml" -print 2> /dev/null`; do let "count+=$(grep -c @drawable/$file $SRCFILE)"; done; for SRCFILE in `find $PROJECT -name "*.java" -print 2> /dev/null`; do let "count+=$(grep -c R.drawable.$file $SRCFILE)"; done; if [ $count -lt 1 ]; then echo -e "$file not used"; else echo -e "$file used"; fi; done;
```

Comment: I updated my question with a link to a script I have written. This script might be also interesting for you. (I am always impressed on people writing bash scripts... +1 :)

Comment: OMFG!!! I just gave it a try and you did an awesome work! Really... thanks, it will be very helpful.

Comment: Brilliant. Worked great for me. I had to change the 8 to a 9 to specify the file name however. I also changed the drawable folder path slightly since the app in question uses extra folders for pixel density and orientation.

Comment: Works great! Though I had to replace `sed 's/\..\+//g'` with `cut -d \. -f1` - the former was returning full filename, with extension (`.png` or `.9.png`).

That's on Mac with zsh

Answer (score 10):

Check this:
http://code.google.com/p/android-unused-resources

**UPDATE 14.12.2011:** Now you can find unused resources and many more as simple as possible. Update to ADT 16 and use [Android Lint](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint). It is really amazing tool. It can find **all** unused resources (not only strings) and many more. From its official site:

```
Here are some examples of the types of errors that it looks for:

- Missing translations (and unused translations)
- Layout performance problems (all the issues the old layoutopt tool used to find, and more)
- Unused resources
- Inconsistent array sizes (when arrays are defined in multiple configurations)
- Accessibility and internationalization problems (hardcoded strings, missing contentDescription, etc)
- Icon problems (like missing densities, duplicate icons, wrong sizes, etc)
- Usability problems (like not specifying an input type on a text field)
- Manifest errors
and many more.
```