# How to remove with eclipse all the resources (images, mp3, xml) that are not been used on the app?

Tags: android, eclipse

Five months later, i am near to finish my Android app, but now i noticed that in the folder of resources, i have a lot of non used old XML's and a lot of non used old .png's on the sub-folders LAYOUT and DRAWABLE

Is there a way on eclipse to remove all these unused resources at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse does not have that feature. However, you can try one of this answers to know which resources are unused and remove them manually:

[Find out if resource is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760033/find-out-if-resource-is-used)